# pn532 read phone indataexchange

Tags: nfc

I'm a college student. My partner used APP to emulate a card, and my mission is using pn532 to read it.

First, I send wake-up and SAMconfig command to pn532 by uart:

```
55 55 00 00 00.....D4 14 01...
```

and pn532 return correct response like picture

Second, I send inlistPassiveTarget command to pn532 getting UID of the phone:

'...0xD4 0x4A 0x01...' , and get UID is 'BF A1 8B B6'.

Lastly, I send InDataExchange command to pn532:

```
'D4 40 01 00 A4 04 05 FF FF FF FF FF...'
```

But pn532 return '... D5 41 27 C3 00' rather than '...D5 41 00...'

[image: Image description here]

Comment: First of all, `00 A4 04 05 FF FF FF FF FF` is not a vaild SELECT APDU. Did you forget a zero between 04 and 05? I.e. send `00 A4 04 00 05 FF FF FF FF FF` Also, if you expect any response data from that command, you should add an Le byte: `00 A4 04 00 05 FF FF FF FF FF 00`. However, this still does not explain your error code. Error code 0x27 indicates that the InDataExchange command contains parameters that are not allowed in the current context. Are you sure that the PN532 is not reset inbetween the InListPassiveTarget and InDataExchange commands?

Comment: You might also want to try to re-issue the InListPassiveTarget command whenever you get status code 0x27 in response to InDataExchange...

Comment: You're right, it's '00 A4 04 00 05 FF FF FF FF FF'. I used three while loop before. In the loop, I will send command first. If I get correct response by pn532 ,it will break and go to the next loop .Apparently ,it's not a good way. So I merged the second and third while loop, and got the correct response 'd5 41 00'. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: So did repeatedly executing the InListPassiveTarget solve the issue? Or did you accidentally send other commands in between InListPassiveTarget and InDataExchange that made the InDataExchange fail?